# Magento: Unable to get sub-categories with SOAP api in Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, soap, magento-1.9, soap-client

I am trying to fetch all the categories and sub-categories using SOAP `v2_soap` for Magento 1.x. but I am not getting the sub-categories in the api response. For client login, I used `gem 'savon', '~> 2.11.1'`. see below my configurations for SOAP user and role.

**System > Web Services > SOAP/XML-RPC-Users**

[image]

[image]

**System > Web Services > SOAP/XML-RPC-Roles**

Role Info:
[image]

Role resources:

[image]

[image]

Role Info:
[image]

Categories:
[image]

All set now.

Now, I am trying to fetch all the categories and subcategories using SOAP api call with url http://127.0.0.1/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl. Getting below JSON response without subcategories.

```
=> {:category_id=>"1",
 :parent_id=>"0",
 :name=>"Root Catalog",
 :position=>"0",
 :level=>"0",
 :children=>
  {:item=>{:"@xsi:type"=>"ns1:catalogCategoryEntity"}, :"@soap_enc:array_type"=>"ns1:catalogCategoryEntity[1]", :"@xsi:type"=>"ns1:ArrayOfCatalogCategoryEntities"},
 :"@xsi:type"=>"ns1:catalogCategoryTree"}
```

I am stuck here. Please help to fix this issue.